# I have a Password problem can some one help

Tags: 12.04, password, sudo

I am a new Ubuntu user with 12.04 lts and stepped away from my computer for a month and forgot my password.

Using this forum I attempted to reset my password using a root line upon booting in grub, I followed instructions to find I was getting results that no one else had gotten. asking for reset options that I didn't understand how to use, it said the the argument was invalid, So I found a way to delete my encrypted password in a nano list. I was able to log in but Sudo still seems to recognize a Password and even thought my user account profile says "none" after password I can't seem to do anything.

I don't know what else to do, hopefully it can be fixed. the long explanation was to show my inexperience and give light to any mistakes made.

Thank you

Comment: Which question or answer did you refer to when resetting the password?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password this was one of them the rest were the same with simple variations, but this has the post with the nano instructions "drastic measures"

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot from live CD/USB
2. Mount partition that has the issue at `/tmp`
3. Chroot into `/tmp`
4. Do `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/USERNAME`
5. Add `USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to file
6. Remove live usb, boot normally
7. Do `sudo passwd root`, this will set root pass

Might work, haven't tried it in a while, but sounds right.

Comment: I was sure it was going to work but after rebooting sudo passwd root prompted for a password.

Comment: Did you put your username in place of `USERNAME`?

Comment: Yes, minding caps as well.